# Nested Sortable Knockoutjs, Ability to convert task in to subtask and vice versa

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I am trying to make a nested sortable list (nesting up to 2 level only). I tried using RP Neimeyers sortable plugin but I need some more functionality like

1. Sub item should be able to become parent item
2. Parent item should be able to become sub item.
3. If item with sub items is dragged in to any parent item, that parent item should go in to perticular parent item as sub item and it's subitems should become primary items. (not sure if this is possible)
4. maintaing indexing for both parent and sub items..

What I have achieved so far -

1. Indexing of parent items
2. Dragging of parent items to change priority.

I am stuck on : 
1. Maintaining indexing for sub items
2. Ability to convert main item a sub item and vice versa.

My attempt on JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/83QrY/

All the code is given in KnockoutJS..

I am using `self.Tasks.withIndex("Position", 0, 0);` to maintain indexing. I hope someone will definitely help me on achieving this..

PS : I am not asking the solution, I want some help on achieving this. I also need to learn it :-)

Regards.
RP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few tips:

- the `connectClass` option determines which sortables can drag and drop with each other. The top-level sortable has it set to "Tasks", which prevents the `SubTasks` lists from being able to interoperate with the parents. So, you could remove the `connectClass` option from the parent to allow dropping between parent/child
- when you drop between parent and child, you would have to ensure that their structure was the same for binding, otherwise you would have to do some mapping. for your sample, I would probably drop the mapping plugin and create a `TaskModel` that supports all of your observable properties that you could use for Tasks and Sub-Tasks. Otherwise, you could use the `beforeMove` callback to map `arg.item` to the correct format, splice it manually (using `arg.TargetParent` and `arg.TargetIndex`), then set `arg.cancelDrop` equal to true.
- the `withIndex` extension is a way that I like to maintain the index. In the `TaskModel` constructor, you can create the `SubTasks` observableArray with the indexing added.  Otherwise, you could have to use the mapping options of the mapping plugin to try to make that happen.
- you might need some styling to help the user know whether they are dropping in the parent or child list.
- if you drop a parent with sub-tasks into an existing list of sub-tasks, then I am not sure what you want to do with the sub-tasks that existed on the original. that might be a case where you want to use `beforeMove` to extract the Sub-Tasks.

Here is a sample with the first 3 updates: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5V3rK/

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This will help me to get started very fast :-) I will let you know if I get stuck anywhere

Comment: Hi @RP Niemeyer... I tried it, working as expected.. the only thing I found weird is when I drag Task with subtasks inside it into Another Main task, all it's subtasks are gone. I am unable to track where the tasks are going..

Comment: The last point you mentioned. If I drop "Main Task" with subtasks in existing list of sub-tasks, then The "Main task" should become the subtask and all it's child tasks should be promoted to Main task..